# Is "Is it his job to always be available?" correct?

Tags: questions, cleft-constructions

Which of the following sentences is correct? For which reasons?

- Is it his job to always be available?
- Is his job to always be available?

Comment: Both are perfectly valid and effectively mean the same thing. There would rarely if ever be a context where you couldn't use either as a mater of stylistic choice. The same applies to the placement of ***always***, which could come before *it/his, to, be,* or *available* (or come at the *end* of the sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Khan said, the first one is a matter of emphasis. In this case, the speaker is perhaps more surprised that the subject is always available for his work, and would perhaps have been assuming (maybe because of the type of job that the subject does) that he works a job where he is only working on a regular pattern, rather than shift work or 'on call' (e.g. 9am-5pm, Monday to Friday).

The second sentence is more of a casual question, and may be a rhetorical question or throw-away comment, simply said in response to something happening that is more expected. It also feels to me like a slightly more sarcastic way of putting it, as if the speaker is suggesting that the subject doesn't actually need to always be available for his job, but is perhaps trying hard to look good to his boss, or maybe is too weak to say 'no' to being called to work.

If the two were spoken, you may notice that the first one might have a higher rise in pitch than the second, which perhaps contributes to the emphasis of disbelief.

Essentially, it feels to me that the main emphasis is whether:

1. The speaker is surprised that the subject needs to be always available, or;
2. The speaker knows that the subject doesn't need to be, but is expressing disapproval that he is always available anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference in meaning between these two sentence. Sometimes, we use the pronoun "it" to emphasize a part of a sentence. Here in the first sentence, it emphasizes HIS JOB. Is it his job (not anybody else's) to always be available?
On the other hand, there is not such an emphasis on his job in the second sentence. There may be other person(s) whose job is also to always be available.